# Can somebody explain this piece of python code to me?

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out what the subsequent lines of python code actually do:

```
if (var1 and var1) in [ctl for key, value in list(uof.items()) for ctl, com in list(cd.items()) if com == 'spain']:
    my_var= uof_map[var1 ]
```

I assume it executes some kind of the following logic:

```
for key, values in list(uof.items()):
  for ctl, com in list(values.items()):
     if com == 'spain':
```

But apparently the results do differ. Can someone please point me into the right direction?

Notes:

`uof` is a dictionary of dictionaries

`value` is a dictionary

Comment: can you give an example of a key,value in uof?

Comment: You are sure that the code is correct?

Comment: At the very least, the first set of parens are almost certainly not in the right place.

Comment: What is `var1`? Why is there a `(var1 and var1)` in the upper code block?

Comment: The duplicates explain the list comprehension construct generally and nested list comps specifically, if you have other questions about that code please be very specific. `(var1 and var1)` will just evaluate to `var1`, so it seems suspicious and is maybe not the best thing to learn from.

Comment: I'm working on getting the info requested.